# What does a Letter of Intent contain?

Tags: aircraft-purchase

When operators purchase new aircraft it seems that a [Letter of Intent](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/when-buying-airliners-what-is-the-difference-between-orders-options-and-pu) is frequently the means by which this is done. What does such a Letter of intent usually contain?

Bonus question: Would the letters of intent in the following two scenarios would look different:

1. **Purchase of a new aircraft as the launch customer from and established manufacturer.** For example: ANA was the launch customer for the 787, which was a new type certificate from company with an established track record of manufacturing airplanes.
2. **Purchase of a new aircraft as the launch customer from a new(er) manufacturer.** For example, Continental Express purchased 25 ERJ-145 at a time when Embraer was not an established manufacturer of commercial passenger aircraft.

Would the purchases in scenario 2 expect more/better assurances as part of the LoI  to minimize certain risks (e.g. planned partners, production planning, certification planning, etc.)?